# How to reference an axis label, e.g. xlabel

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, coordinates

I'm new to that forum but it already helped a lot, thanks for this!

But now I really got stuck. Basically I'm looking for a possiblity to reference the `xlabel` of an axis in a TikZ picture. The intention is to read out the `xlabel` coordinates. Later on I would like to use them to position another node in a specific way with respect to the these coordinates.

With `xlabel style={name=xlabel}` I tried to assign the xlabel name in the axis options. Within the axis I wanted to point to it with `xlabel.north` (like it is possible to point to the axis itself with `current axis.north`).

Unfortunately it didn't work. I was told:

```
no shape named xlabel is known
```

So I guess, that naming the `xlabel` in the axis options is wrong. Is there a way to solve this problem?

I hope the question is stated such that one can understand what I'm trying to say...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add thanks, simply use upvoting to acknowledge good answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably trying to access the `xlabel` node before it's created (hard to tell without an example document).

If you put the drawing command inside the `axis`, the label won't exist yet (it gets placed only after the axis is finished). You'll have to put it outside the axis:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=X label,
    xlabel style={name=xlabel}
  ]
  \addplot {rnd};
  \end{axis}
  \draw [ultra thick, latex-] (xlabel.south east) -- ++(1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I think case is closed :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using "pure" tikz (i.e: no `pgfplots` which would be a completely different issue), the idea is to name some coordinates at the ends of the line, and then build a node which contains both (using `fit` library). This node can be named as you required. You can only give names to nodes (and coordinates which are a particular type of dimensionless node).

Following is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (start) at (0,0);
\coordinate (end) at (3,0);
\draw[->] (start) -- (end);
\node[fit=(start) (end), draw=none, inner sep=1pt] (axis) {};

% The line is contained in node "axis" which we can use
\draw (axis.south) node[below] {Foo}
      (axis.east)  node[right] {Bar}
      (axis.west)  node[left]  {XX};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And produces:

[image]